# I want to create a range in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following cells:

```
    Number  Band    Color
1   10    A          A1
2   20    A          A1
3   30    A          A1
4   40    B          A1
5   50    B          A2
6   60    C          B1
7   70    C          B1
8   80    A          B1
9   90    A          A1
10  100   B          A1
```

I want to create a "range"/summary of the data as follows:

```
Start  End  Band    Color
10     30   A        A1
40     40   B        A1
50     50   B        A2
60     70   C        B1
```

I can do this by hand, but the data is in the 1000s of cells, therefore it seems tedious. Are there built in functions to help facilitate this?

Comment: So since B - A1 is in twice and not consecutive it would have two lines in the output?

Comment: Yeah, it's start and end would be different. One at 40-40 and the other at 100-100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this with two Helper columns.  I put the following formulas in D2 and E2 respecctively:

```
=IF(OR(B2<>B1,C2<>C1),A2,"")
=IF(OR(B2<>B3,C2<>C3),A2,"")
```

Then copied down the length of the dataset.

[image]

This gave me a list on which I can use the SMALL() formula to get the Start and Finish.

In G2 I put:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(D:D,ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then copied over one column and down till I got blank cells.

Then we use those numbers in a INDEX/MATCH to return the other Information.

In I2 I put:

```
=IF($G2<>"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH($G2,$A:$A,0)),"")
```

Copied over one column and down till I got blanks.

I could have done the same with VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP($G2,$A:$C,COLUMN(B:B),FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent use of helper columns *(+1)*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent learned from the best........you know, Telyn. :P. Just kidding, I channeled my inner GS.  WWGSD

Comment: Wow! Some excel magic there. I will go through this thoroughly to completely understand it (no good just copying without understanding). Thank you so much!

Comment: I must have started typing my answer right as you put yours in. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Your question could you a little more explanation, both the pattern and the tools you want to use. I will assume when you say "function" that you want sheet formulas, not VBA code. Are you only looking at the first instance of each band/color pair or you are looking for consecutive matching band and color set all the way down? If the latter, your table would actually include three more rows as follows:

```
Start  End  Band    Color
10     30   A        A1
40     40   B        A1
50     50   B        A2
60     70   C        B1
80     80   A        B1
90     90   A        A1
100    100  B        A1
```

If you want this longer table, you can create two new rows (either in this sheet or a new one) and, assuming you have "Number" in A1, use the following code:

Cell D2 `=IF(NOT(AND($B1=$B2,$C1=$C2)),IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("D1:D"&ROW(D2)-1))+1,1),0)`

Cell E2 `=IF(NOT(AND($B2=$B3,$C2=$C3)),IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("E1:E"&ROW(E2)-1))+1,1),0)`

Extend the code down the full column length of your table. The result will be as follows.

```
Number Band Color Start End
10     A    A1    1     0
20     A    A1    0     0
30     A    A1    0     1
40     B    A1    2     2
50     B    A2    3     3
60     C    B1    4     0
70     C    B1    0     4
80     A    B1    5     5
90     A    A1    6     6
100    B    A1    7     7
```

From here, just look up the number of each set (1,2,3,...) and find the row number to get the information your after. If you place the Start/End columns first, you can use `vlookup` for this.

If you only want the first appearance of each pair (but then why is row 8 left out?), you'll need a little more logic. That may require an additional column, but the extra logic will be fairly simple.

Comment: I started with integers but then realized that we wanted numbers anyways and they were sorted so there was no need to convert then convert back.

Comment: I agree. Your answer is definitely cleaner for this problem. I just find the integer count helpful often enough in my files that it's ingrained in my thought process.